# Error: ER_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocal requested by server consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

I have tried a lot of solutions that have been provided on
Stack Overflow to solve this error. However, none of them really solved my error. I'm just a newbie in SQL.

By the way, I'm using visual studio code for IDE.

The error I face when I write SQL in VSCode:

[image: The error I face when I write SQL in VSCode]

Comment: Looks like you have two issues.  The first is a style issue surrounding the *unsigned* integer in your query, and the second issue, is a authentication protocol incompatibly.   The style error isn’t a show stopper and isn’t the source of the authentication error

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near 'UNSIGNED' ` vscode ide told me that. However, I can't find the problem in my code.

Comment: vscode ide also told me that `code language not supported and defined.` But I have already installed Mysql extension and Mysql syntax extension in vscode.

Comment: Syntax errors belong on Stack Overflow not Super User. However, your other issue, would be within scope. There just isn't enough information to answer your question. You should provide your connection string. Did you enable Strong or Legacy authentication when you installed MySQL? You should edit your question to include this vital information instead of submitting comments. What version of MySQL?

Comment: [You have numerous syntax errors in your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639788/sql-create-table-error).  Once you provide the information about the Strong vs Legacy authentication with regards to My SQL I can answer your question.  You should also indicate exactly what you have tried.  So I don't spend time suggesting something you have already tried.

Comment: Where can I find out whether I've enabled Strong or Legacy authentication or not? I'm using MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried a lot of solution that have been provided on Stack Overflow to solve this error.

`ER_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE` is caused by your client attempting to use an authentication mode  your server does not support.  In order to resolve this issue, provided you are using MySQL 8.0, you need to reconfigure your server to support Legacy mode.

[image]

You can do that by modifying your current installation and choosing to reconfigure the server.

[image]

> Incorrect syntax near 'UNSIGNED'

Is caused by several syntax errors.

```
CREATE TABLE 'Customers' (
    'CustomerID' INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    'NAME' CHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    'Address' CHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    'City' CHAR(30) NOT NULL
};
```

Source:

- [SQL CREATE TABLE Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639788/sql-create-table-error)
- [ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE - MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946270/er-not-supported-auth-mode-mysql-server/52726522)

Comment: The problems solved! Thank you so much!